# What is the cause of the flash of light and debris immediately above this explosion?

Tags: thermodynamics, explosions

First - the footage of the explosion in question:

http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos/homemade-diamond-high-speed/

More specifically, about 5 seconds in,

[image]

I'm speaking of the flash of light above the explosion.

The explosion was described as "a 20 foot high wooden tube packed with 5,000 pounds of high explosives."

Comment: At a guess, some of the top part of the explosive was boosted as a rocket from the mass bellow and is exploding in air. The cone must be gas material from ejection

Answer (score 4):

It's internal reflection in the camera.  It's an inverted image of the actual exploding material.

Comment: I think so too - explosion is extremely bright with high contrast. You sometimes see this with sun, but usually conditions are not so extreme and it's less visible. It's sometimes called flare or lens flare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare

Comment: you are wrong. If you watch the video frame frame, the ball and cone fall @JarosławKomar. It is a flaming ball with its gass exhaust.

Comment: It's a reflection of the exploding material.  As the material is rising in the frame, the reflection is moving down.

Comment: And this is not necessarily wholly internal. Probably they've put some protective glass shield (just like you would use UV filter which does nothing to photo if you are below say 4000 m a.s.l. but protects lens mechanically) in front of camera. More likely than not this is back reflection from lens reflected  back from this protective glass.

Comment: @JarosławKomar watch frame by frame, the whole is falling. you are wrong about reflection. the ball is geometrically different with respect to what is happening on the ground.too clean an image.

Comment: @annav Of course it's different - it's off focus. And then it reflects off slightly different part of lens with every frame - so it's further distorted. Front lens isn't flat. I've met this exact problem while trying to shoot electrical welding, so I'm pretty sure that's it.

Comment: The reflected image will always be (much) lower intensity.  That means that in cases where the primary is very overexposed, the reflected image can actually appear sharper.

Comment: What is off focus? if something were it should be the putative reflection, as the experiment is concentrating on the ground and would be surely focused there. The tail of the cone is transparent and looks like lace! is that a reflection from the much larger mess on the ground?

Comment: @annav - The lace effect is the interaction of the fireball with the ground. The "real" image is grossly overexposed, including the "skirt" around the explosion itself, caused by reflected light. The ghost image, being much dimmer than the real image, shows details that you can't otherwise see, and this includes that fact that the  skirt is much dimmer than the fireball. And for what it's worth, the shape of the cone shows that the detonator was located at the base of the charge, not the top.

Answer (score -1):

Watching the video frame frame one sees that an incandescent ball is falling and a tail of gasses follows. The ball must have been ejected from the tube by the rest of the explosion, like a rocket, and falling, generates a tail of incandescent gasses.

My argument against a reflection is that the ball ( falling in my view) and its cone/fan tail are too symmetric to be a reflection of the total mess on the ground.

Comment: It is pretty, much nicer than the lower part. That's because it's enough dimmer that you can't see the reflected "mess". Also, if you step through the frames, you'll see that the upper image appears simultaneously with the lower. This cannot be an ejected ball, since at those speeds it would not possibly have reached its peak height in a few milliseconds - you'd see it rising. Also, note the bright rectangle at the top of the lower cone- clearly a lens artifact since it is stationary.